# NodeJS using single quotes instead of double quotes in object [Answered]

Tags: node.js, express

[Answered by: [Loulou BadWeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19277982/loulou-badweed)]

> Hi @NickP. , did you stringify/serialize your payload before passing
> it in the fetch body ? Does not seem the case from your example and I
> don't think fetch does that for you. Try JSON.stringify(config) in the
> body argument of the fetch function

I have a "small" problem.

I can't figure out, why nodejs uses single quotes for the string value instead of double quotes...

My Code

```
let config = {}
config["active"] = 1
config["domain"] = req.body.domain
config["mailboxes"] = req.body.mailboxes
config["defquota"] = req.body.defquota
config["maxquota"] = req.body.maxquota
config["quota"] = req.body.quota
config["restart_sogo"] = 10
            
console.log(req.body.domain)
console.log(config)
```

What I input:

```
{
  "domain": "domain.tld",
  "mailboxes": 10,
  "defquota": 512,
  "maxquota": 1024,
  "quota": 10240
}
```

What I get:

```
{
  active: 1,
  domain: 'domain.tld',
  mailboxes: 10,
  defquota: 512,
  maxquota: 1024,
  quota: 10240,
  restart_sogo: 10
}
```

The problem I have with this, is that the mailcow api doesn't like single quotes in the request body. :) Does anyone know, why this happens and can help me?

I tried replacing the single quotes with str.replace() or str.replaceAll(). But that didn't work. I tried using both types where I used the '' outside of the "".

I also already asked ChatGPT for help, but the results were just the replace and replaceAll...

PS: It's 4:30 AM when I wrote this. I'm not at 100% of my usual capacity. So please don't hate me for my question.

Comment: What you're describing is a linter just formatting your code. Single or double quote won't matter in the general sense - they are both strings. What is the exact error you receive from Mailcow API? And what does the code look like that puts that final object you showed into the API request method? It seems like you may be missing a JSON.stringify() call or something.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your message.

The error that I get is `{ type: 'error', msg: "Request body doesn't contain valid json!" }`.

I'm using this code to send an http request. [Link to pastefy.ga](https://pastefy.ga/Ka40MMqR)

I think mailcow is only accepting double quotes and not single quotes for strings.

Comment: Hi @NickP. , did you stringify/serialize your payload before passing it in the fetch body ? Does not seem the case from your example and I don't think fetch does that for you. Try JSON.stringify(config) in the body argument of the fetch function

Comment: Omg... That just did it. I didn't even think about that  Thank you so much! <3